# MemoryStream leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, memorystream

can anyone tell us what's wrong with this code below?
we have here an object serializer that should return an XML string of any object passed to it.

we've been scratching our heads over this one, as we have a program that calls this multiple times and we see our memory usage going sky high (and staying there even after the program was done).. we've done searches but to no avail. the stream object is inside a "using" statement so we thought this was supposed to be disposed on its own.. help please.

```
    public static string ToXML(this IMessage m)
    {          
        try
        {
            var serializer = SerializerFactory.Create(m.GetType());
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(new[] { m }, stream);
                stream.Position = 0;
                var s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray());
                return s;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return string.Format("Message unserializable: {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

btw SerializerFactory looks like this:

```
public class SerializerFactory
{
    public static IMessageSerializer Create(Type t)
    {
        var types = new List<Type> { t };
        var mapper = new MessageMapper();
        mapper.Initialize(types);
        var serializer = new XmlMessageSerializer(mapper);

        serializer.Initialize(types);

        return serializer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is no memory pressure so the GC is just taking it easy.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong here. Have you tried running it through a memory profiler?

Comment: Any exceptions being thrown? You are passing stream to serializer call. So i am having a bit of doubt there, i mean about streams life time being extended much beyond its using() locale.

Comment: i think it's best we run it through a memory profiler. it doesn't really throw any exception, just that reports tells us that our memory usage goes high and stays there. we tried the program whilst removing a call to this ToXML.. and lo and behold, the memory usage was fine. but exactly which part of this code is messing up is what's really driving us crazy..

Comment: As per my answer - is this `XmlSerializer` under the wrappings? If so: can you show exactly how you are creating the serializer instance?

Comment: will update answer re your edit

Comment: apparently some of the objects here are NServiceBus' objects.. like the IMessageSerializer and etc.. may be we could look more into it.. or perhaps use another implementation instead (with the plain XMLSerializer class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing *hugely* wrong with that code; note that `using` is *essentially* a no-op on a `MemoryStream`, since it only has *managed* resources, and managed resources are the domain of the GC; it is normal for the GC not to worry hugely until it makes *sense* to collect some memory, so I wouldn't stress too much - or: if there is a problem, it probably isn't this.

One observation, though, would be that you can avoid a buffer in the encode step:

```
var s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
```

and actually, I'd be tempted to use UTF8 by default, not ASCII.

A final thought: is your `SerializerFactory` *itself* doing something that leaks? For example, are you creating a `new XmlSerializer(...)` via any of the *more complex* constructors? The simplest form:

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeType));
```

is *fine* - it internally caches the *internal/actual* serializer per-type, and re-uses this for each `XmlSerializer` instance created this way. However, it does *not* do this caching for the more complex constructor overloads: it creates and loads a new dynamic assembly each time. And assemblies loaded in this way ***are never unloaded*** - so yes, *that* can cause a memory leak. I would be very keen to see how the serializer instances are created, to see if *that* is the actual problem. Note that such cases are usually very easy to fix by creating your own serializer-cache in the factory:

```
public class SerializerFactory
{
    // hashtable has better threading semantics than dictionary, honest!
    private static readonly Hashtable cache = new Hashtable();
    public static IMessageSerializer Create(Type t)
    {
        var found = (IMessageSerializer)cache[t];
        if(found != null) return found;

        lock(cache)
        {   // double-checked
            found = (IMessageSerializer)cache[t];
            if(found != null) return found;

            var types = new List<Type> { t };
            var mapper = new MessageMapper();
            mapper.Initialize(types);
            var serializer = new XmlMessageSerializer(mapper);

            serializer.Initialize(types);

            cache[t] = serializer;

            return serializer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: added the SerializerFactory as edit. thanks and we'll have a look on this

Comment: @user1307017 edited to add a serializer-cache to your `Create` method

Comment: HOLY CRAP... the modification did all the magic. you were right, we were bombarding our program using the old code without caching anything... like in 100,000 times.. we were dynamically creating assemblies.. now we applied that fix, and everything is perfect. thanks!!!

Comment: @user1307017 yeah, been bitten by that in the past; it isn't something you forget quickly ;p

Answer (score 3):

Memory leak does not happen on `MemoryStream`, it actually happens on `XmlSerializer`:

> “This overload of the XmlSerializer constructor does not cache the dynamically generated assembly, but generates a new temporary assembly every time you instantiate a new XmlSerializer! The app is leaking unmanaged memory in the form of temporary assemblies.”

Take a look on this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx

Instead of creating `XmlSerializer` everytime, you need to *cache* for each type, to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, this is similar with Marc's. it worked and we've learned something new today